# Linearity of derivative

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be an open set and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in U$ if there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+T(h)+r(h)$$
where $\lim_{h\to 0}r(h)/|h| = 0$. The above equality holds provided $x+h \in U$. From now on, $T$ will be denoted by $f'(x)$.

Now, my advanced calculus book states the following: if $f$ is differentiable at $x \in U$ then, for every $h \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ we have:
$$f'(x)(h) = \frac{f'(x)(th)}{t} = \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} \pm \frac{r(th)}{|th|}|h| $$
for every $t \neq 0$ real. Thus:
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x)(h) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}

**Question:** $f'(x)$ is supposed to be linear in $h$ and, at a first glance, (\ref{1}) does'nt seem linear in $h$ to me. How can I prove $f'(x)$ is indeed linear in $h$ using (\ref{1})?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You state in your question that differentiability requires the existence of a linear $T$ such that
$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + Th + o(h), h \to 0 $$
If that holds (that is if $f'(x) = T$ is linear), *then* $f'(x)$ is given by (1). The other direction is not true, you can't prove from the existence of the limits in (1) that $f'(x)$ is linear.

Comment: Hm, I see! But then it seems possible to prove it using (\ref{1}) together with $f(x+h)=f(x) + T(h) + r(h)$, $r(h) \to 0$ which is the condition for differentiability. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}{}$